# Reorganizing data from 3 rows to 1

Tags: r, csv, reshape2

I need to reorganize data from a csv file that contains mostly repeating data. I have the data imported into R in a dataframe but I am having trouble with the following:

```
ID   Language  Author   Keyword
12   eng       Rob      COLOR=Red
12   eng       Rob      SIZE=Large
12   eng       Rob      DD=1
15   eng       John     COLOR=Red
15   eng       John     SIZE=Medium
15   eng       John     DD=2
```

What I need to do is transform this into a row with each keyword in a separate column

```
ID   Language  Author  COLOR  SIZE      DD
12   eng       Rob     Red    Large     1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `reshape2` package this is straightforward:

With `tt` defined as in [Gary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15032524/892313)

```
library("reshape2")

tt <- cbind(tt, colsplit(tt$Keyword, "=", c("Name", "Value")))
tt_new <- dcast(tt, ID + Language + Author ~ Name, value.var="Value")
```

which gives

```
> tt_new
  ID Language Author COLOR DD   SIZE
1 12      eng    Rob   Red  1  Large
2 15      eng   John   Red  2 Medium
```

Comment: I am able to get this to work but after the dcast() runs I get an error saying: Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length.  I then get a 1 in each of the new variables.  I guess in the real dataset there must be something that is not right as it works fine on this simplified data set.  Any ideas?

Comment: It seems I have unequal numbers somewhere.  Need to figure out how to find the ID with more than 3 rows and clean it up.

Comment: You would get that warning if there is a combination of `ID`, `Language`, `Author`, and `Name` that appears more than once. You can tell which one it is/ones they are by looking for a value other than 1 in the result (essentially, when there are multiple values for a combination, reshape will aggregate them into a single value somehow, and by default, that somehow is just counting how many there are).

Answer (score 6):

Using `plyr` ans `strsplit` you can do something like this :

```
library(plyr)
res <- ddply(dat,.(ID,Language,Author),function(x){
        unlist(sapply(strsplit(x$Keyword,'='),'[',2))
})

colnames(res)[4:6] <- c('COLOR','SIZE','DD')

 ID Language Author COLOR   SIZE DD
1 12      eng    Rob   Red  Large  1
2 15      eng   John   Red Medium  2
```

**Edit:** Here is a generalization that addresses @Brian's concern:

```
res <- ddply(dat,.(ID,Language,Author), function(x){
             kv <- strsplit(x$Keyword, '=')
             setNames(sapply(kv, `[`, 2),
                      sapply(kv, `[`, 1)) })
```

Comment: As a point of caution, this does assume that the keywords are always `COLOR`, `SIZE` and `DD` and always in that order. If that assumption is true, this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `reshape2`:

```
tt <- read.table(header=T,text='ID   Language  Author   Keyword
 12   eng       Rob      COLOR=Red
 12   eng       Rob      SIZE=Large
 12   eng       Rob      DD=1
 15   eng       John     COLOR=Red
 15   eng       John     SIZE=Medium
 15   eng       John     DD=2')

tt$Keyword <- as.character(tt$Keyword)

tt <- transform(tt, key_val = lapply(tt$Keyword,function(x) strsplit(x,'=')[[1]][2]),
 key_var = lapply(tt$Keyword,function(x) strsplit(x,'=')[[1]][1]))

tt_new <- dcast (tt, ID + Language + Author ~ key_var, value.var='key_val')
```

Comment: Your `lapply`'s should be `sapply`'s and you need a `value.var="key_val"` in your `dcast` call.

Comment: Didn't realize `value.var` needed the var in quotes, so it gave me an error. I left it out but `dcast` guessed the right variable appropriately in this case.  Thanks.