# How do I reorganize data in R consisting of 8 repeating rows, with 24 columns?

Tags: python, c++, r, excel, formatting

I'm quite new to R, so please be patient with me (at the same time I'll try to respect your time by being as descriptive as possible).

I've got data that I've been trying to format properly for a while now that describes 8 measurements taken every hour for a little over a year. Because of the way that I had to retrieve the data, the spreadsheet I have now lists the data in a tabular format, with the 8 variable names listed as repeating rows, and each hour of the day as a separate column, like this:

```
var1[0] var1[1] var1[2] var1[3] var1[4] var1[5] var1[6] var1[7] var1[8] var1[9] var1[10] var1[11] var1[12] var1[13] var1[14] var1[15] var1[16] var1[17] var1[18] var1[19] var1[20] var1[21] var1[22] var1[23]
var3[0] var2[1] var2[2] var2[3] var2[4] var2[5] var2[6] var2[7] var2[8] var2[9] var2[10] var2[11] var2[12] var2[13] var2[14] var2[15] var2[16] var2[17] var2[18] var2[19] var2[20] var2[21] var2[22] var2[23]
var3[0] var3[1] var3[2] var3[3] var3[4] var3[5] var3[6] var3[7] var3[8] var3[9] var3[10] var3[11] var3[12] var3[13] var3[14] var3[15] var3[16] var3[17] var3[18] var3[19] var3[20] var3[21] var3[22] var3[23]
var4[0] var4[1] var4[2] var4[3] var4[4] var4[5] var4[6] var4[7] var4[8] var4[9] var4[10] var4[11] var4[12] var4[13] var4[14] var4[15] var4[16] var4[17] var4[18] var4[19] var4[20] var4[21] var4[22] var4[23]
var5[0] var5[1] var5[2] var5[3] var5[4] var5[5] var5[6] var5[7] var5[8] var5[9] var5[10] var5[11] var5[12] var5[13] var5[14] var5[15] var5[16] var5[17] var5[18] var5[19] var5[20] var5[21] var5[22] var5[23]
var6[0] var6[1] var6[2] var6[3] var6[4] var6[5] var6[6] var6[7] var6[8] var6[9] var6[10] var6[11] var6[12] var6[13] var6[14] var6[15] var6[16] var6[17] var6[18] var6[19] var6[20] var6[21] var6[22] var6[23]
var7[0] var7[1] var7[2] var7[3] var7[4] var7[5] var7[6] var7[7] var7[8] var7[9] var7[10] var7[11] var7[12] var7[13] var7[14] var7[15] var7[16] var7[17] var7[18] var7[19] var7[20] var7[21] var7[22] var7[23]
var8[0] var8[1] var8[2] var8[3] var8[4] var8[5] var8[6] var8[7] var8[8] var8[9] var8[10] var8[11] var8[12] var8[13] var8[14] var8[15] var8[16] var8[17] var8[18] var8[19] var8[20] var8[21] var8[22] var8[23]

var1[24] var1[25] var1[26] var1[27] var1[28] var1[29] var1[30] var1[31] var1[32] var1[33] var1[34] var1[35] var1[36] var1[37] var1[38] var1[39] var1[40] var1[41] var1[42] var1[43] var1[44] var1[45] var1[46] var1[47]
var2[24] var2[25] var2[26] var2[27] var2[28] var2[29] var2[30] var2[31] var2[32] var2[33] var2[34] var2[35] var2[36] var2[37] var2[38] var2[39] var2[40] var2[41] var2[42] var2[43] var2[44] var2[45] var2[46] var2[47]
var3[24] var3[25] var3[26] var3[27] var3[28] var3[29] var3[30] var3[31] var3[32] var3[33] var3[34] var3[35] var3[36] var3[37] var3[38] var3[39] var3[40] var3[41] var3[42] var3[43] var3[44] var3[45] var3[46] var3[47]
var4[24] var4[25] var4[26] var4[27] var4[28] var4[29] var4[30] var4[31] var4[32] var4[33] var4[34] var4[35] var4[36] var4[37] var4[38] var4[39] var4[40] var4[41] var4[42] var4[43] var4[44] var4[45] var4[46] var4[47]
var5[24] var5[25] var5[26] var5[27] var5[28] var5[29] var5[30] var5[31] var5[32] var5[33] var5[34] var5[35] var5[36] var5[37] var5[38] var5[39] var5[40] var5[41] var5[42] var5[43] var5[44] var5[45] var5[46] var5[47]
var6[24] var6[25] var6[26] var6[27] var6[28] var6[29] var6[30] var6[31] var6[32] var6[33] var6[34] var6[35] var6[36] var6[37] var6[38] var6[39] var6[40] var6[41] var6[42] var6[43] var6[44] var6[45] var6[46] var6[47]
var7[24] var7[25] var7[26] var7[27] var7[28] var7[29] var7[30] var7[31] var7[32] var7[33] var7[34] var7[35] var7[36] var7[37] var7[38] var7[39] var7[40] var7[41] var7[42] var7[43] var7[44] var7[45] var7[46] var7[47]
var8[24] var8[25] var8[26] var8[27] var8[28] var8[29] var8[30] var8[31] var8[32] var8[33] var8[34] var8[35] var8[36] var8[37] var8[38] var8[39] var8[40] var8[41] var8[42] var8[43] var8[44] var8[45] var8[46] var8[47]
```

There was initially quite a bit more to the data, but I've stripped it down to this in an effort to get to the bottom of the issues I've been having. (In the above example, what I'm trying to imply is that at each hour (t1, t2, t3, etc.) the variables (var1, var2, var3, etc.) are recorded.

My goal is to reformat it so that it resembles something like this:

```
var1[0] var2[0] var3[0] var4[0] var5[0] var6[0] var7[0] var8[0]
var1[1] var2[1] var3[1] var4[1] var5[1] var6[1] var7[1] var8[1]
var1[2] var2[2] var3[2] var4[2] var5[2] var6[2] var7[2] var7[2]
var1[3] var2[3] var3[3] var4[3] var5[3] var6[3] var7[3] var7[3]
.       .       .       .       .       .       .       .
.       .       .       .       .       .       .       .
.       .       .       .       .       .       .       .
[all the way to 9216, which is the number of hours in 384 days]
```

So far, I've tried working with it in Excel at length and cannot find a way to do this. I've also looked into writing a C++ script as I've done before, but I feel like there may be a simpler way. My latest effort has been to turn to R, as I've been trying to learn it and I hear that it is well-suited for this kind of data manipulation. With R, I attempted to follow an example I found that had me recreate the data as a matrix of a different length (found [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Averaging_a_sequence_in_blocks/)), but this led to fantastically erroneous data. (I'm sure I probably misused the method). I also looked into the solution discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032270/reorganizing-data-from-3-rows-to-1), but I was unable to modify the code to work with my situation. Perhaps I'm overlooking something simple?

Does anyone have any suggestions? As I said, at this point I'm trying to do this in R, but I'm open to suggestions in Excel, C, or python. (I'm definitely open to suggestions in other languages but that'll probably require a bit more thorough explanation :) )

Thanks!

[edit:]

The above data samples were meant to be descriptive. Below is what the actual first 25 lines of the data looks like; the only change I've made is to substitute the variable names for confidentiality reasons:

```
Metric,Year,Month,Day,DOW,12am,1am,2am,3am,4am,5am,6am,7am,8am,9am,10am,11am,12pm,1pm,2pm,3pm,4pm,5pm,6pm,7pm,8pm,9pm,10pm,11pm
varA,2013,1,20,Sun,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,22,10,18,24,26,11,21,24,10,0,0,0,0,0
varB,2013,1,20,Sun,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,13,18,28,26,25,25,21,23,13,0,0,0,0,0
varC,2013,1,20,Sun,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,7,9,5,1,4,4,1,7,1,0,0,0,0
varD,2013,1,20,Sun,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,23,17,27,29,27,15,25,25,17,1,0,0,0,0
varE,2013,1,20,Sun,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,44,32,33,65,37,42,62,75,71,50,0,0,0,0,0
varF,2013,1,20,Sun,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,89,82,83,94,37,77,100,100,90,60,0,0,0,0,0
varG,2013,1,20,Sun,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,100,95,100,100,100,100,100,0,0,0,0,0
varH,2013,1,20,Sun,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,10,92,12,101,34,14,64,29,86,0,0,0,0,0
varA,2013,1,21,Mon,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,12,23,20,22,24,9,19,15,12,13,9,0,0,0
varB,2013,1,21,Mon,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,14,21,27,26,23,19,22,16,16,16,12,0,0,0
varC,2013,1,21,Mon,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,5,4,10,6,10,2,7,7,4,5,5,0,0,0
varD,2013,1,21,Mon,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,18,27,30,28,34,12,26,22,16,18,14,0,0,0
varE,2013,1,21,Mon,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,20,15,67,33,71,47,36,64,58,67,0,0,0
varF,2013,1,21,Mon,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,60,70,45,70,90,67,100,100,79,91,92,89,0,0,0
varG,2013,1,21,Mon,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,100,100,94,100,100,100,91,100,100,0,0,0
varH,2013,1,21,Mon,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,12,31,20,29,16,12,12,16,16,34,41,0,0,0
varA,2013,1,22,Tue,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,14,18,25,16,20,22,11,23,13,9,4,0,0,0
varB,2013,1,22,Tue,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,23,17,28,14,18,30,17,27,17,17,6,0,0,0
varC,2013,1,22,Tue,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,8,2,3,2,6,7,2,4,1,2,1,0,0,0
varD,2013,1,22,Tue,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,22,20,29,18,26,29,13,27,14,11,5,0,0,0
varE,2013,1,22,Tue,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,83,90,43,30,29,17,32,60,71,54,89,100,0,0,0
varF,2013,1,22,Tue,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,100,86,65,43,56,74,90,90,73,100,100,0,0,0
varG,2013,1,22,Tue,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,0,0,0
varH,2013,1,22,Tue,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,23,17,30,16,14,12,8,9,13,14,6,0,0,0
```

As you can see, in the full dataset there are five additional columns at the beginning corresponding to the variable names, as well as date information.

Comment: We need more information about your file format. Is the above a real example of what your file looks like or just descriptive? Can you provide a snippet of your file? Are the values tab-separated? space-separated? can values have spaces inside them? do you use quotes in your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in matrix `M`, this should work:

```
output <- NULL
last.count <- 9216/8 - 1
for (i in 0:last.count) {
  output <- rbind(output, t(M[8*i + 1:8,]))
}
```

ps: `rbind` can be slow (depending on the data size), in which case you can pre-allocate `output` matrix

Comment: That did it! For some reason it also generated about 18,000 rows of "NA" columns after the 9241 rows of data, but I deleted these, then I double-checked and the data points are spot-on accurate. Thank you so much!

Comment: May be, pl check the dimensions properly. Tweak the number of rows accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Hadley's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley) reshape2 package to make this easy!
First let's make some data, as you didn't give us any. For the future use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) as a guide.

```
foo<- matrix(rnorm(8*9216),nrow=8) #matrix of 8 rows 
#(8 variables and 9216 - 384 x 24 columns
rownames(foo)<-paste0("V",1:nrow(foo)) #giving rownames, 
#you can use "var" here if you want
foo<-data.frame(foo) #making it a data.frame
names(foo)[1:9216]<-paste0("t",0:(ncol(foo)-1)) #time points,
#starting at 0, t0,t1,...t9215
foo <-data.frame(id=rownames(foo),foo) #making sure id column is first
#load the reshape2 library
library(reshape2)
foo.wide <- recast(foo,id ~ variable) #we use the variable id as the id column,
#play with melt and cast to understand what's going on here
#do ?melt, ? cast and look at the examples
#foo.wide is a list with data and labels.

#code below to transform the list in foo.wide to a data.frame
foo.wide.df <-foo.wide$data 
names(foo.wide.df)<-unlist(foo.wide$labels[[2]])
row.names(foo.wide.df)<-unlist(foo.wide$labels[[1]])
```

Hope this helps

Update: just saw you posted example data.
you can use the additional 5 columns id columns
use the code below to `recast`

```
foo.wide.df <-recast(foo, id ~ variable, id.var=1:5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Nishanth's solution has given me the results I was after already, but I'll look into your solution as well, and I'll definitely use the guide you referred to in the future if I need to ask questions. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! and reshape2 is much faster than using for loops in R.Best to avoid loops in R, as they can be really slow.